# How to automate non-concurrent specific row heights in Excel

Tags: excel

Okay so I know there's this code

```
Sub sbChangeRowHeight()

'Changing the 3rd row Height
Rows(3).RowHeight = 25

End Sub
```

for adjusting one height in a row.

And this one for adjusting multiple heights (in a row)

```
Sub sbChangeRowHeightMulti()

'Changing the 3rd-25the row Height
Rows("3:25").RowHeight = 25

End Sub
```

what if I want every "certain number" of rows to be a certain height? For example, every sixth row is automatically 25 regardless of if there's content in it or not. Or if that's not possible, to have non-concurrent rows be editable at the same time (row 6, row 8, etc).

Please literally ELI5 or write out any code exactly how it is supposed to be if possible I don't code and I'm dumb LMAO. Thank you so much!

Thanks!

-Rachel

Comment: you can use a for loop: `For i = 3 to 100 step 6` then `Rows(i).RowHeight = 25` the `Step 6` would make i jump 6 rows at a time.

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for your help. I did that an it says error invalid outside procedure. I hit f5 after entering it and then i saved the macro and this came up For i = 3 To 100 Step 4
Rows(i).RowHeight = 83.25
Sub Test1()
 
End Sub                                                                          I don't know what to do, I'm just trying to do this thing for work. The code is supposed to be on two different lines right (the for i = 3 to 100 step 4 on one line and then the rows(i).rowheight = 3 on the other? thanks @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this - change the start/end row, height and interval as required.

```vb
Sub ChangeHeight()
Dim rng As Range
Dim dblHeight As Double
Dim lngStartRow As Long
Dim lngEndRow As Long
Dim lngInterval As Long
Dim idxRow As Long

    dblHeight = 25
    lngStartRow = 1
    lngEndRow = 100
    lngInterval = 5
    
    For idxRow = lngStartRow To lngEndRow Step lngInterval
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Rows(idxRow)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(idxRow))
        End If
    Next idxRow
    
    rng.RowHeight = dblHeight
    
End Sub
```